# Как обратиться к методам второго потока из другого диалогового окна

Tags: c++, qt

Создал диалоговое окно "X" из главного окна. Создал второй поток в диалоговом окне "X". Закрыл окно "X", но второй поток еще существует (время существования потока бесконечно). Хочу обратиться с методам второго потока из главного окна, но как мне это сделать? Указатель на объект остался у меня в окне "X". Как мне передать указатель на объект из окна "X" в главное окно?

Comment: если поток на базе QThread то сигнал в слот ему послать

Comment: А если у меня не одно диалоговое окно? Допустим диалоговых окно X1, X2,X3,X4 и я создал второй поток в окне X4 а мне нужно передать указатель на объект потока в X1. То как тут поможет сигнал---слот?

Comment: не понятно, что вы там делаете, но иногда не обязательно делать сигнал и connect, можно вызвать слот обьекта через `QMetaObject::invokeMethod`, когда вы посылаете сигнал Qt в конечном итоге этой функцией и пользуется

Answer (score 1):

Концепция QT - сигнал-слоты. лучше избегать прямого обращения к методам. 
Правильнее как-то так:

```
for(int i=0;i<100500;i++){
  QThread* thread = new QThread();
  MyObject* obj = new MyObject();
  obj->moveToThread(thread);
.... // тут всякая шелуха с запуском/остановкой потока
  connect(this, SIGNAL(sendToAll(QString message)), obj,SLOT(slotInMessage(QString message))); // сигнал из основного потока привязываем к слотам во всех потоках
  thread->start();
}
emit sendToAll("чмоки всем"); // все ваши потоки получат сообщение
```

Comment: В вашем примере вы создали 100500 потоков и отправили один сигнал всем. А как отправить сигнал sendtoall из другого диалогового окна?  Создали окно "меню" из "меню" переход в окно "график" вот как из этого "график" послать сигнал sendtoall?

Comment: ровно так же. 
...
dlg = new GraphDlg();
connect(dlg, SIGNAL(out()),this,SLOT(fromGraph()));
из "график"
emit out();

Comment: если надо из диалога отправить всем потокам
connect(dlg,SIGNAL(out(QString message)),this,SIGNAL(sendToAll(QString message));
сигнал диалога привяжется к сигналу основного потока, который приязан к слотам всех потоков (из первого примера)